# Kmeans elbow method not returning an elbow

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

So following the example in documentation ([here](http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html)):

> The KElbowVisualizer implements the “elbow” method to help data scientists 
>   select the optimal number of clusters by fitting the model with a range of 
>    values for K. If the line chart resembles an arm, then the “elbow” (the 
>   point of inflection on the curve) is a good indication that the underlying 
>   model fits best at that point.

What if there is no elbow in the chart? When I run the same code on my data set the output is:
[image]

So the distortion score keeps increasing for every additional cluster.

However, when I run another example of the elbow method, using the kmeans.intertia attribute:

```
sse = {}
for k in range(1, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=1000).fit(testDF)
    testDF["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_
    #print(data["clusters"])
    sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_ # Inertia: Sum of distances of samples to their 
closest cluster center
plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()))
plt.xlabel("Number of cluster")
plt.ylabel("SSE")
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

Which does have an elbow.

What is the difference between these two methods? 
Why is there no elbow on the first graph?

According to documentation they both apply the same distance method, i.e. "Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center."

Comment: i think the difference is in number of iterations. please give more iterations for KElbowVisualizer and update.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of KElbowVisualizer, I don't see a way to increase the iteration count.

Comment: can you paste your KElbowVisualizer  code?

Comment: the KElbowVisualizer code is exactly as in the documentation (http://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html) exception being that X is my dataset.

Comment: ok in that case your model KMeans() passed to KElbowVisualizer  has argument max_iter. Change it to 1000 as well before passing to KElbowVisualizer .

Comment: Thanks, I tried different values for max_iter in both methods but they yielded roughly same answer regardless of max_iter. So same as seen in my question.

Comment: There is no elbow in the second one either. This dropoff is a typical 1/k curve indicating that the quality is bad as uniform data - it failed. The first method clearly is defect though...

Comment: Because this 1/k drop is even seen on random data, the elbow method does not make much sense (use a different maximum k, and you'll likely "see" a different elbow), the VRC makes just much more sense because it corrects for this effect.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate please? Do you mean using calinski_harabaz or the silhouette method to determine the cluster count? or should I look to use a different method than k-means to cluster the data?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now and updating to Yellowbrick v1.1 fixed it.

`pip install -U yellowbrick`

or in a Jupyter cell:

`!pip install -U yellowbrick`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and the elbow-point showed up after updating the k-modes (am clustering binary data):

```
pip install -U kmodes
```